# coalesce.go:200: warning: cannot overwrite table with non table for notifiers (map[])

Tags: kubernetes, grafana, grafana-alerts, kube-prometheus-stack

In grafana charts I try to add notifiers and getting the error. The notifiers conf is below:

```
notifiers: {}
    - name: email-notifier
      type: email
      uid: email1
      # either:
      org_id: 1
      # or
      org_name: Main Org.
      is_default: true
      settings:
        addresses: an_email_address@example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical part was missing there were

**notifiers.yaml:**

**notifiers:**

in

```
notifiers: {}
  notifiers.yaml:
    notifiers:
    - name: email-notifier
      type: email
      uid: email1
      # either:
      org_id: 1
      # or
      org_name: Main Org.
      is_default: true
      settings:
        addresses: an_email_address@example.com
```